# ¿Por qué no hace la búsqueda mi botón en C# web services?

Tags: c#, .net

amigos.

Estoy trabajando con C# en web services, sin embargo, en mi consulta de SQL server paso los dos parámetros que quiero que consulte mi WS pero me marca error alguien me puede ayudar?  dejo mi código

```
[WebMethod]
    //public DataSet WSbusca(string item)
     public DataSet WSbusca(string item,string tienda)
    {


SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Item],[Location] FROM [products] WHERE [Item]='" + item + "' AND [Location]='" + tienda + "' ", conn);
```

Comment: Que error marca? [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/425580/edit) tu pregunta y agrega ese dato "importante"

Comment: Perdon amigo por no redactar correcto, con esa consulta no marca error simplemente no hace nada de busqueda.
tengo dos Textbox y un boton, no se si, asi esten bien declarados para el filtro.
 




{
        Wspersonal.WSbuscarSoapClient WS = new 
        
       Wspersonal.WSbuscarSoapClient();
       
       DataSet ds = WS.WSbusca(TextBox1.Text);
      
        DataSet ds2 = WS.WSbusca(TextBox2.Text);
      
       GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     
       GridView1.DataBind();

    }

Comment: Creo que lo que dice sergio y @RogerTomé es valido no colocas como haces para alimentar el DataAdapter y el Fill donde esta? eso lo debes colocar en tu webmethod... edite tu llamado al servicio y allí tienes 2 dataset, creo que deberías tener un dataset y enviar 2 parametros (item, tienda) como text1 y text 2? que es lo que veo que estas confundido. recuerda cuando vayas a editar tu pregunta no lo colocas en comentarios sino en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El SqlDataAdapter por si sólo no hace nada, te falta declarar el objeto que quieres alimentar (en este caso un Dataset) y llamar al método .Fill() del SqlDataAdapter para volcar los datos en el Dataset. Este DataSet es lo que debe devolver tu función en última instancia.

Aquí lo explica con ejemplos: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter

Comment: Hola @Sergio. Recuerda que debes consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»